# Snapping closest to vertex is not working as expected

Tags: edit-mode, vertices, snapping

I had 2 different objects one of which had array modifier. I have applied all of the modifiers and joined two object into a single mesh. So in the edit mode I wanted to snap closest vertex of one object to the other. But what I am experiencing is, it is not behaving as supposed to behave. I snaps as if **Snap With** option is **Center** instead of closest.

And my pivot point is not chosen as individual origins. Attaching the screenshot of the behavior.

Two areas marked with blue are not snapping as expected, as closest should work. But starting from the mesh marked with red when snapping it acts as expected and snaps just fine. Let me know please if you need more info. [image]

Comment: ..I  find myself playing a game of 'spot the difference', here, and I'm losing :)  Could you show the parts, separated, before the snapping move? (BTW, Have suspicions that there may be better ways than snapping, in this case)

Comment: I merged all the vertices and the thing is there is no difference between all the parts. Some just work fine some are not. And what ways you have in your mind?